# Mongodb: "Network error while attempting to run command 'getlasterror' on host" when updating data

Tags: mongodb

I update data in mongodb with robo3t and get error: "Network error while attempting to run command 'getlasterror' on host.."
Has anybody got ideas about this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you're connected to the primary.

I was having the same issue moments ago and it turned out I had a typo in the domain name of the database server, so I had inadvertently hit the load balancer and reached a non-primary replica.

Comment: I tried to write to a MongoDB cluster running in Kubernetes with port forward. I forwarded the service and thought this would just work. Seems it might forward you then to a non primary pod and you can't write. Using port forward with a single pod (the primary one) worked then. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Thorsten Yes, you need to make sure you can talk to the primary. In clusters with more than one node you need to make sure that your service can talk to all nodes which can potentially become primary (all voters). I'm happy my comment helped!